# Dropdown with categories and subcategories

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I have 2 tables in SQL.

`Category_Tbl`:

```
ID  Categories 
1   Projects 
2   Residential 
3   Commercial
```

`SubCategory_Tbl`:

```
ID  CATID   Subcategories
1   1   Residential  Projects
2   1   Commercial Projects
3   2   Residential Apartment
4   2   Independent/Builder Floor
5   2   Independent House/Villa
6   2   Residential Land
7   2   Studio Apartment
8   2   Farm House
9   2   Serviced Apartments
10  3   Commercial Shops
11  3   Commercial Showrooms
12  3   Commercial Office/Space
13  3   Commercial Land/Inst. Land
```

I want to bind all the categories and its subcategories into the dropdown list with checkbox. Something like

[image]

I have searched Google but nothing valuable result for this.

Comment: Set data source of main dropdownlist to a collection of categories returned from data access.  When selected index changed event is called on main dropdown, a call is made to retrieve sub-categories corresponding to main category ID equal to main dropodownlist's selected value and that collection becomes secondary dropdown collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to plug another company but I have (on many occasions) used Kendo UI treeview for this sort of thing. Kinda does the work for you. This is taken from their basic HTML5 demo (no html5 in use here).

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

Here is a fiddle that you can look at but really is just setting up your datasource. I would probably load the datasource via ajax (or serialized json) to simplify how you create the treeview.

http://jsfiddle.net/ztc4ma52/3/

With some little work you can clean up the styles a bit and make it look very similar to what you have done.

Sample Fiddle Code.

```
$(function () {
    $('#list1').kendoTreeView({

        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        check: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        },
        dataSource: [{
            catid: 1,
            text: "Projects",
            expanded: true,
            items: [{
                subcatid: 2,
                catid: 1,
                text: "Residential Projects"
            }, {
                subcatid: 3,
                catid: 1,
                text: "Commercial Projects"
            }],
        }, {
            catid: 2,
            text: "Residential",
            expanded: true,
            items: [{
                subcatid: 3,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Residential Apartment'
            }, {
                subcatid: 4,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Independent/Builder Floor'
            }, {
                subcatid: 5,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Independent House / Villa'
            }, {
                subcatid: 6,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Residential Land'
            }, {
                subcatid: 7,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Studio Apartment'
            }, {
                subcatid: 8,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Farm House'
            }, {
                subcatid: 9,
                catid: 2,
                text: 'Serviced Apartments'
            }]
        }, {
            catid: 3,
            text: "Commercial",
            expanded: true,
            items: [{
                subcatid: 10,
                catid: 3,
                text: 'Commercial Shops'
            }, {
                subcatid: 11,
                catid: 3,
                text: 'Commercial Showrooms'
            }, {
                subcatid: 11,
                catid: 3,
                text: 'Commercial Office/Space'
            }, {
                subcatid: 11,
                catid: 3,
                text: 'Commercial Land/Inst. Land'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

As per the comment. If you would like to bind directly from your SQL server you could manage this using simple queries. If you are using `Asp.Net Webforms` (which I think you are) we can just cheat and return the serialized JSON data using `Newtonsoft JSON.Net` which comes pre-packed with the starter apps http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Here is a very simple example generating a simple JSON string from your data model:

```
public partial class TreeView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string GetTreeViewJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetTreeView());
    }

    public IEnumerable<CategoryRootTreeModel> GetTreeView()
    {
        List<CategoryRootTreeModel> items = new List<CategoryRootTreeModel>();
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Category_Tbl]", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new CategoryRootTreeModel
                    {
                        catid = (int)reader["ID"],
                        expanded = true,
                        text = reader["Categories"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        items.ForEach(item => bindSubCategeories(item));
        return items;
    }

    void bindSubCategeories(CategoryRootTreeModel model)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SubCategory_Tbl] WHERE CATID = @p0", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", model.catid);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    model.items.Add(new CategoryTreeItemModel
                    {
                        catid = (int)reader["ID"],
                        subcatid = (int)reader["CATID"],
                        text = reader["Subcategories"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }



}

public class CategoryRootTreeModel
{
    public CategoryRootTreeModel()
    {
        this.items = new List<CategoryTreeItemModel>();
    }

    public string text { get; set; }

    public bool expanded { get; set; }

    public int catid { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryTreeItemModel> items { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryTreeItemModel
{
    public string text { get; set; }

    public int catid { get; set; }

    public int subcatid { get; set; }
}
```

That can then be called in your aspx file such as

`<%= GetTreeViewJson() %>`

This will output a really long string such as...

```
[{"text":"Projects","expanded":true,"catid":1,"items":[{"text":"Residential Projects","catid":1,"subcatid":1},{"text":"Commercial Projects","catid":2,"subcatid":1},{"text":"Residential Apartment","catid":3,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Independent/Builder Floor","catid":4,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Independent House/Villa","catid":5,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Residential Land","catid":6,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Studio Apartment","catid":7,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Farm House","catid":8,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Service Apartments","catid":9,"subcatid":2},{"text":"Commercial Shops","catid":10,"subcatid":3},{"text":"Commercial Showrooms","catid":11,"subcatid":3},{"text":"Commercial Office/Space","catid":12,"subcatid":3},{"text":"Commercial Land/Inst. Land","catid":13,"subcatid":3}]},{"text":"Residential","expanded":true,"catid":2,"items":[{"text":"Residential Projects","catid":1,"subcatid":1},{"text":"Commercial Projects","catid":2,"subcatid":1},{"text":"Residential Apartment","catid":3,"subcatid":2},.....]
```

Now we have the serialized data into our view we can easily add this to the kendo data source such as...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <div id="list1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#list1').kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true
                },
                dataSource:<%= GetTreeViewJson() %>
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Now this is sort of hacky to do it this way as I would rather return a nice JSON response through ajax but ends up with a very simple list as the JS fiddle shows.

More information:

To get the checked values from the TreeView you can follow the API Guides provided by Telerik, notably the check event.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-check

Here is a sample :
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

In the sample they are responding to the `check` event and creating a javascript array using a function `checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes)` this is a function they have provided as a sample. You could adapt this to change the value of a textbox that you have on the page such as.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CheckedFields" Text="" /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveFields" Text="Save Fields" OnClick="SaveFields_Click" />

<div id="list1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].catid);
            }

            if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    }

    // show checked node IDs on datasource change
    function onCheck() {
        var checkedNodes = [],
            treeView = $("#list1").data("kendoTreeView")
        checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
        $('#<%= CheckedFields.ClientID %>').val(checkedNodes.join(', '));
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#list1').kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
            },
            check: onCheck,
            dataSource:<%= GetTreeViewJson() %>
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will trigger the change of id's to a comma seperated array using 'checkedNodes.join(',')' method. Now you will find that you may need to find more information however each `node` in the array `nodes[]` contains all the fields you have passed in from your code behind available (plus a few extras) you could get very creative with how you keep track of your checked options.

Cheers

Comment: That was superb @Nico but i want to bind the data from `SQL` and have not so much knowledge of `webservices` :(

Comment: Getting syntex error on ` dataSource:<%= GetTreeViewJson() %>
                });`  jquery code @Nico

Comment: Have you tried running the sample? The visual studio intellisense doesnt like that example as it to visual studio is not valid javascript :)

Comment: Now getting the error ` Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.`

Comment: From the example remove the `<asp:Content />` tags as these should already exist in your pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76962/discussion-between-gitz-and-nico).

Comment: Thanks a lot working fine. But the last question is how do i get the values which i have checked ??

Comment: Sir please can you tell me how do i get the checked values ?? :(

Comment: @Gitz I have edited the answer again. Please review the Kendo docs well as they usually provide clues to the answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ddlCategory.DataSource = CategoryDataAcces.GetAllMain();
ddlCategory.DataBind();

private void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (ddlCategory.SelectedIndex < 0) 
        return;

    int categoryID = int.Parse(ddlCategoryID.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ddlSubCategory.DataSource = CategoryDataAccess.GetByCategoryID(categoryID);
    ddlSubCategiry.DataBind();
}
```

No access to programming environment, except I think this should help get you started.

Comment: need semicolon after `return`

Comment: Thanks.  Still getting used to tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bootstrap multiselect plugin. You can find out more in this example:

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data source for your first table i.e. "Categories" to dropdown list.

Then On Dropdown list OnSelectedItem event get the id of selected category. And Pass it to query which find the sub-catogories. Then bind it again to dropdownlist

Take look into this.
http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/dropdowncheckboxes-or-drop-down-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-1100.aspx

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html

Comment: Can you please give a small example for that ?

Comment: you can find example on above links. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: i already visited this site but this is for only categories.i want to bind categories and subcategories both